# Compact Version of Hightcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to release a compact version of highcharts library, only for line charts or area charts for example, just like the way of jquery ui. Because the size of 130k (220k together with jquery) is still large particularly in mobile browser. Thanks for you attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now is not possible, but the work on in it the future; here is the provided suggestion on the highchart site: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2321414-make-a-build-process-to-reduce-js-size-select-on?tracking_code=f0e8c63eb43e70c9e0a6ee0c78244afd

Feel free to vote up the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

highcharts.js (130kb) is minimalized version of highcharts.src.js (430kb), so only what comes to my mind is use gzip on the server which will compress javascripts (jquery/highcharts).